# Search period, given current week and year

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table, which has the following columns:

```
id | description | startYear | startWeek | endYear | endWeek
```

startYear, startWeek, endYear and endWeek are all integer

So given current week and year (for example week 4, year 2017), how do I search for rows that have startYear, startWeek and endYear, endWeek that include the given week and year?

I'm currently trying to doing this manually by UNION-ing several select query, but I think it's inefficient, and not too mention too much codes (relatively, if there's some sort of built-in query to do this).

My query currently look something like this:

```
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear = startYear AND
       (:currentWeek >= startWeek OR 
        :currentWeek <= endWeek ))
UNION
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear > startYear AND
       :currentWeek <= endWeek )
UNION
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear < endYear AND
       :currentWeek <= 53 )
UNION
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear < endYear AND
       :currentWeek <= 53 )
UNION
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear < endYear AND
       :currentWeek <= 53 )
UNION
Select id, description
from myTable
where (:currentYear = endYear AND
       :currentWeek <= endWeek);
```

Comment: @CL added my query above

Comment: SQLite supports DATE Strings, which would be alot easier to process IMO than individual fields

Comment: Though, isn't each UNION essentially another OR statement on the WHERE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a query of the form:

```
SELECT ... WHERE A
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE B
```

you can trivially transform it into a single query of the form:

```
SELECT ... WHERE A OR B
```

The WHERE condition might then be further simplified by using the rules of the Boolean algebra.

But your current query is wrong, so it's better to construct a new one from scratch.

What you want is the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE currentTime BETWEEN startTime AND endTime;
```

Now, instead of splitting the time comparisons into the two fields, it would be easier to construct a single time value. Just multiplying the year by `100` and summing it with the week gives a value like `201704`, which compares correctly with any other such values:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE :currentYear * 100 + :currentWeek
      BETWEEN startYear * 100 + startWeek
      AND     endYear   * 100 + endWeek;
```